# Je crois à/en l'existence de Dieu

Tags: sens, prépositions, synonymes

I have read about the difference between "croire à" and "croire en" in other questions.

- croire à qqch: to believe in the existence or veracity of sth (sth. may be a fictional character or a group of people)
- croire en qqch/qqun: to have trust/faith in sth./sb. It is the one idiomatically used to express faith in the existence of God.

My understanding is that "to have faith in sth which is not proven to exist" is identical "to believe in its existence". Is that right? If so, both sentences below are identical.

Je crois à l'existence de Dieu/extraterrestres.

Je crois en l'existence de Dieu/extraterrestres.

Comment: The meanings are overlapping but are fully not identical. *Croire à* means you believe that it is scientifically possible, despite being unproven, *croire en* means you just do not question the existence and are not interested in a scientific proof.

Comment: A counter-argument: If "an enfant croit au Père Noël" , he/she does not care about any scientific proof.

Comment: @jiliagre I had already read that question you suggested before creating this one, but I was not able to infer answer to my question from it.

Comment: I wrote the meaning are overlapping in my reply so that means they are not identical. The issue with your counter-argument is that neither *croire à Dieu* nor *croire en Père Noël* do exists. There is a strong difference between a kid believing Santa Claus exists because he has seen him face to face, and has received very concrete "proofs" of his existence in the form of Christmas presents and believers who have generally a less concrete experience with miracles and God in general.

Comment: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/l-de-l-allemagne

Comment: **en = à la** pas vrai?

Comment: I have not said the meanings are not overlapping or that they are identical at any moment. I just can not clearly understand the difference (yet). I can not see any difference between someone believing in Santa Claus because he/she has found Christmas presents on Christmas and a religious person believing in God because of miracles. There is no real proof in any of these cases, just faith. I do not understand what you meant by "a child who has seen Santa Claus", that has never happened and therefore it is not what justifies childrens' faith on him.

Comment: Going back to the definitions you gave, I just cannot understand exactly what "to believe that is scientifically possible, despite being unproven" means. It seems a paradox to me. Either I *know* it is true because I know the scientific proof or I *believe* it is true because I don't know the scientific proof (that is, either it is not scientifically proven or it is scientifically proven but I do not know the proof yet). I am not able to see a middle ground, specially on a religious context. Maybe my scientific mind is blocking my understanding of this matter.

Comment: There is a [theological account](https://books.google.fr/books?id=pHzsDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT290&lpg=PT290&dq=%22solecisme+chretien%22&source=bl&ots=35qotb-2-O&sig=ACfU3U0oqsyOVQUVgfiHkO0JD-oJvkmfdw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfjLOS4JvjAhXkyIUKHYKzAE8Q6AEwA3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22solecisme%20chretien%22&f=false) on the 'credere in' / 'croire en' phrase. I've heard it referred to as 'le solécisme chrétien'. I've also heard the 'in' / 'en' is paramount in the eyes of a Christian, but I'm not sure why. More if I find the time!

Comment: You did wrote the meaning of "to have faith in sth which is not proven to exist" **is identical** "to believe in its existence". Kids believe Santa Claus exist because they were provided convincing evidences. On the other hands, if they believe in God, it is not because of experience (miracles do not happen every year in every house) but because they trust the people who told or teach them God exists. In the first case what they have been told is confirmed by their "scientific experiment" while in the second case, they trust someone else, they abandon their critical spirit.

Comment: Kids **do** see Santa Claus live on TV, shopping centers, and sometimes even at home.

Comment: @messerbill Non, **en** `!=` **à la**. Cette preposition est plus proche de **dans** ici.

Comment: For me "to have faith in sth which is not proven to exist" is definitely not identical "to believe in its existence". If you say *the evidence is still inconclusive but I believe the most plausible hypothesis is X*, you are expressing a belief that is evidence based and can be expected to change if new evidence comes to light.

Comment: On the other hand, if you say *I have faith in the existence of leprechauns*, you are saying that you believe in them as a matter of deep personal conviction, not because of any evidence you can point to - not on intersubjective grounds at all - but because it seems to you that the world just has to be that way, or the existence of leprechauns was directly revealed to you in a dream or mystical experience that was (obviously) personal to you. That kind of belief doesn't really change when the evidence changes, because it is not based on evidence in the first place.

Comment: Some might want to argue that it is evidence, and it's just that it's not publicly available - but on that view there is still a distinction, just a different one.